# Как определить ошибку через отладчик Chrome?

Tags: javascript

Почему не срабатывает методы split и join? Через отладчик Chrome не получается определить причину.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler() {
  var data = document.getElementById('in_1c').value;
  var position = document.querySelector('.container');
  if (data != 0) {
    position.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p class="data">${data.split(' ').join('\n').toUpperCase()}</p>
        </div>
      `);
  } else {
    var warningEl = document.createElement('div');
    warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning');
    var message = document.createTextNode('Пожалуйста, заполните соотвествующие поля для обработки!');
    warningEl.appendChild(message);
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
    e.appendChild(warningEl);
  }
}


function resetValue1() {
  textArea = document.getElementById('in_1c');
  textArea.value = "";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--<form action="">-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!--d-flex-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="in_1c">(Введите 2 раза, например: RS-CS18AX/RU-18AX1)</label>
        <textarea name="" id="in_1c" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue1();" value="Очистить"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы решили, что *split* или *join* не работают? Они работают.

Если нужно выводить каждое слово в отдельной строке, то лучше это сделать через тег `p`.

Пример.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler() {
  var data = document.getElementById('in_1c').value;
  var position = document.querySelector('.container');
  if (data != 0) {
    position.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            ${data.split(/\s/).map(m=>`<p class="data">${m.toUpperCase()}</p>`).join('')}
        </div>
      `);
  } else {
    var warningEl = document.createElement('div');
    warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning');
    var message = document.createTextNode('Пожалуйста, заполните соотвествующие поля для обработки!');
    warningEl.appendChild(message);
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
    e.appendChild(warningEl);
  }
}


function resetValue1() {
  textArea = document.getElementById('in_1c');
  textArea.value = "";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--<form action="">-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!--d-flex-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="in_1c">(Введите 2 раза, например: RS-CS18AX/RU-18AX1)</label>
        <textarea name="" id="in_1c" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue1();" value="Очистить"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ikar А что вы подразумеваете под *не рабтает*? А здесь сниппет работает?

Comment: Имел ввиду что insertAdjacentHTML() не выводит данные, которые отформатированы с помощью split() и join(). У меня всё в одну строчку, а надо на разных.

Comment: В вашем примере работает правильно.

Comment: Так они не будут на разных, `htm`l **\n** не учитывает. Делайте или тег `pre` или вставляйте разделители `br` или вставляйте все в абзацы `p`.

Comment: Вы сделали вот такой рефакторинг: ${data.split(' ').map(m=>`<p class="data">${m.toUpperCase()}</p>`).join('')}   Это jquery ($) и ES-2015 (=>)? Спасибо, очень помогли и воодушевили:-)

Comment: Код несколько не правильно работает, после вот такого ввода данных: http://prntscr.com/j6b5ch

Comment: @ikar Дело в том, что `\n!==' '`. Если хотите учиывать все пробельные символы, то можно воспользоваться регулярныи выражением `/\s/`. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: а с помощью регулярных выражений можно выводить вот так? http://prntscr.com/j6bmze  (интересует возможность, а не реализация. На сколько это сложно?)

Comment: @ikar Не очень понятно, что и как выводить. Лучше обновите данный вопрос или задайте новый. Постарайтесь максимально подробно описать, что надо сделать и что сделали.